# Postgresql insert data error when using python

Tags: python, postgresql, jenkins

I am trying to insert data to the table that was created earlier using python script. Here is the code I am trying to execute. I want to insert data into table with date as well.

```
date_today = dt.date.today()

conn = psycopg2.connect(host = serverip, port = port, database = database,    user = uid, password = pwd)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO My_TABLE (Date, Class, Total_students, failed_students, Percent_passed_students) VALUES (date_today, 'Class Name', int1, int2, int3)")

print "Data Inserted successfully"
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Here is the error I see from my job. what am i missing here?

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "date_today" does not exist
```

I created the table using different job with the following query:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE MY_TABL(Date date, Lob varchar(30), Total_Students int, failed_students int, Percent_passed_students int)""")
```

And the table is created with above five columns.

Comment: Variables are not magically replaced in strings.

Comment: You need to pass values not identifiers in `values (...`

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO My_TABLE (Date, Class, Total_students, failed_students, Percent_passed_students) VALUES (date_today, 'Class Name', int1, int2, int3)")
```

Is the incorrect way to dynamically insert values into a database.

---

Here's a functional and correct example:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

---

And applying it in your case...

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO My_TABLE VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (date_today, 'Class Name', int1, int2, int3))
```